# Tomcat / OpenEJB / Eclipse - configuration

Tags: tomcat, configuration, openejb

I need to configure my Tomcat ( 5.5 ) with OpenEJB container and I want to have it all in Eclipse. Could anybody explain me how it works, since when I have installed Tomcat in a directory ( i.e C:/Tomcat/ ) another directory for OpenEJB for Tomcat ( C:/OpenEJB/ ) and when I deploy I have another folder different than the Tomcat's one where the webapp lands ( in Eclipse .metadata ).
There are also two configuration folders, one inside Tomcat directory and one inside Eclipse one. How the config files are propagated ?

I also want to ask is it possible to configure also ANT for this purpose that I will be able also to deploy/redeploy to the server both with ANT and Eclipse ?

Thank you for the input,

Kind regards,
P.

Comment: Did you solve you problem? How?

Answer (score 3):

You might find it easier using Apache TomEE. That's the newer form of OpenEJB-Tomcat- Integration. ( Pre-bundled TomEE is available here at [the OpenEJB Downloads page](http://openejb.apache.org/download.html). )

With TomEE you get the regular installation of Tomcat now added with an openejb webapp.

Apart from a new openejb.xml in the tomcat/conf directory and a logs/openejb.log there's nothing structurally new to this powered up tomcat.

The best part, from a user's point of view is that using it is just like using tomcat. i.e you can use the same plugins, deploy the same way, as you would with tomcat.

So yes, you can deploy using ANT or Eclipse, just the way you would with Tomcat.

A very basic getting started with TomEE video is [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmcajUixCaw).